# Open more than 15 Files by Context Menu without MultipleInvokePromptMinimum

Tags: windows, registry, contextmenu, windows-shell

I have already added a right click option to open files with my c++ program:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open With MyProgram]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myProgram.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open With MyProgram\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myProgram.exe\" \"%1\""
```

This is working just fine. When I select more than 15 files the right click option disappears. 
I already read about the following method with MultipleInvokePromptMinimum:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"MultipleInvokePromptMinimum"=dword:00001388
```

This would do the job, the only problem is that I dont want to enable other "open" or "print" right click options for more than 15 files, just my custom one.

(The "Edit with Notepad++" right click option for example is enabled for more than 15 files without changing the MultipleInvokePromptMinimum)

Whats the best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to set MultiSelectModel to Player? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127436(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks! I set the MultiSelectModel to Player, now I'm able to open up to 100 Files with my right click option. For more than 100 Files the option still appears but it only opens 1 file if i choose it. I guess i have to implement my application as "COM" instead of "Legacy" to open a unlimited number of files with my application. Do you know how I can implement my program as COM?

Comment: I think the simplest way is create IDropTarget shell extension and then add subkey "DropTarget" to your subkey "Open With MyProgram". Inside your IDropTarget shell extension you can do everything you want. For example you can create text file with list of files and pass it to your real "Legacy" app.

Comment: tk_ - How did you managed to open 100 files with context menu? I am trying to achieve this, but my application opens multiple instances. I am trying to select multiple images and click my menu which will pass the list of images to app.

Answer (score 3):

As you have already figured out from the comments, a plain static verb has a limit that can be bumped up to 100 by setting `MultiSelectModel` to `player`. Explorer only allows COM based shell extensions to go beyond this limit.

There are multiple types of shell extensions you could implement depending on your minimum supported Windows version:

- `IExecuteCommand` is the least amount of work but it is only usable on Windows 7 and later. Tutorial/example can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623).
- `IDropTarget` needs a full COM server but works on Windows XP and later. Tutorial/example can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100503-00/?p=14183/).
- `IContextMenu` registered under `ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers` works on every Windows version but the selection limit does not exist on these old systems so there is no need to implement this in your case.

It is recommended that you write your extension in C/C++ or Delphi and not in a .NET language like C# (this is a recommendation or requirement depending on the Windows and .NET version).

Comment: I know its been a while now, but how can I surpass the 100 files minimum?

Comment: @Chibs A normal static entry in the registry cannot bypass the 100 limit. You must implement a shell extension.